# Formula numbering

Tags: numbering, amsart

I want to write a short note using amsart and I wish that the numbering of formulas should be (1), (2) and so on (not (0.1)...) and also that Theorems should get the numbers 1,2, (not (0.1)...).

What should I do to avoid the proliferation of 0. ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{section}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do nothing special:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This states an important fact.
\end{thm}

And we follow with a very important equation
\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You probably have something like

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
```

and

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

otherwise, as you see, the section number is not added.